# How to force mutation sync with React Query

Tags: reactjs, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I am using React Query with a query persistor to give an app offline capabilities. This is working great, if offline the mutation will be persisted to local storage and as soon as the network is online again the mutation(s) will post to the api.

I have run into an issue if the browser refresh button is clicked while mutations have been cached while offline. Once online again the mutations refuse to complete, I can see them in local Storage, so they haven't been lost.

Is this a bug? Is there away I can detect if there are mutations cached and have a click event to force them to fire?

Comment: Can you make a codesandbox to demo this?

Comment: are you using a default mutation function as described here? https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/mutations#persisting-offline-mutations